# Entity Framework SQL Timeout after x number of WCF requests

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, wcf

There are around 300 clients each making requests to a WCF service every ten minutes. They are not all making requests at exactly the same time.

This LINQ query in a Service class is trying to get `configFeedItems` that the client has not already received (note: I'm using Ninject to inject the Repository into my Service class):

```
     var configFeedItems = (from feedItem in configFeedItemRepository.All
                            where feedItem.Id > lastReceivedFeedItemId &&
                            (feedItem.TargetUserId == userId || feedItem.TargetUserId == null) &&
                            !feedItem.ConfigFeedItemReceipts.Any(x => x.User.Id == userId)
                            select feedItem)
                            .ToList();
```

Which causes this exception to be thrown:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
```

This is the SQL that gets generated:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Action] AS [Action], 
[Extent1].[TargetId] AS [TargetId], 
[Extent1].[TargetCommand] AS [TargetCommand], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Extent1].[TargetUserId] AS [TargetUserId], 
[Extent1].[ChannelToUpdate] AS [ChannelToUpdate], 
[Extent1].[CreatedBy_Id] AS [CreatedBy_Id]
FROM [dbo].[ConfigFeedItem] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] > @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[TargetUserId] = @p__linq__1 OR [Extent1].[TargetUserId] IS NULL) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
1 AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[ConfigFeedItemReceipt] AS [Extent2]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[ConfigFeedItem_Id]) AND ([Extent2].[User_Id] = @p__linq__2)))',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__2 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0=0,@p__linq__1='E3D4044F-497E-4EEC-890C-021F72826505',@p__linq__2='E3D4044F-497E-4EEC-890C-021F72826505'
```

If I stop and restart the AppPool in IIS, it's fine for about five minutes and then it happens again.

If I change the LINQ query so it's not pulling in the `ConfigFeedItemReceipts`, I don't get any timeout.
It only seems to happen when I try to query the child collection.
I've tried using joins instead and EF generates a query with a simple LEFT OUTER JOIN but I still get a timeout.
It's like there is a lock or something or the connections are maxed out.

I tried `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` before executing the LINQ query but this didn't make a difference

Any ideas what is causing the SQL timeout?

**UPDATE:** not all requests cause a timeout, some work some don't even though it's the same query.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? Where do you open and *close* the connection/transaction? Do you dispose of the context? What's the execution plan? Does the second table have an index on `User_Id`? Open the Activity Monitor in SQL Server's Management Studio to see the active connections and queries when blocking occurs. Don't

Comment: Same query but different data. If there's no index on `User_Id` and `ConfigFeedItem_Id` the server will have to scan for all relevant feed items then count them. What's the execution plan of the query? How big is this table?

Comment: The lifetime of the DBContext object is handled by Ninject and is specified as InRequestScope(). Looking at the execution plan the most expensive at 95% is a Key LookUp (Clustered) on ConfigFeedItemReceipt (i.e. the child collection). Yes the second table, ConfigFeedItemReceipt, has an index on User_Id and ConfigFeedItem_Id.

Comment: The parent table ConfigFeedItem has 756 rows with a data space of 0.078MB. The child table ConfigFeedItemReceipt has 405030 rows with a data space of 27MB.

Comment: So *are* there any connections/transactions open on SQL Server? Did you close the transaction or did you leave it to NInject to close it? An open transaction will keep the connection open until the context is disposed, where a query outside a transaction will close the connection immediatelly

Comment: There are no open connections/ transactions on SQL Server. I leave it to Ninject to close it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using sql server with code first approach. If so, try to change the default command timeout value during initiating the instance of dbcontext as stated below. Your db operations might take longer than the default timeout.

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext()
        : base("YourConnectionStringName")
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that would help because the same query can timeout for some WCF requests but not for others.